# Invalid url call with json

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I try to call a url with data with the json value

dataExist value is

"{"name":"Robert Trudeau","birthdate":"1991-02-12"}"

```
if (memberFullName != "" && memberBirthdate != "") {

    dataExist = JSON.stringify({name: memberFullName, birthdate: memberBirthdate});

    //check if user exist, it not we continue otherwise we should not
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: getHostName() + "/members/validation",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: dataExist,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            alert(status);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status) {
            checkError(jqXHR);
        }
    });

}
```

On the server i have

```
@GetMapping(value = "/members/validation")
public ResponseEntity<Void> hasUsernameExist(@RequestBody String name, @RequestBody LocalDate birthdate) {
    boolean existing = memberService.hasMemberExist(name, birthdate);

    if (!existing) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

}
```

When the call is done, i get

Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 400, statusText: "error"}, status = "error

Comment: Why are you returning `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` and not `HttpStatus.OK` or `HttpStatus.ACCEPTED` if user exist ?

Comment: HttpStatus.OK or HttpStatus.ACCEPTED could be used but that nothing to do with the question...

Comment: You want name and birthdate in the response instead of error ? I dont understand the question

Comment: from a web page, with this value "{"name":"Robert Trudeau","birthdate":"1991-02-12"}"
i try to call this /members/validation. Actually i get  Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 400, statusText: "error"}, status = "error.
There is something controller don't like

Comment: In ajax call you assume that dataType is json `dataType: 'json'` but the controller return a void body response. Be sure that controller return a json response otherwise remove `dataType: 'json'` from ajax call

Answer (score -1):

Spring can't handle multiple Request Body if you dont override some class.

On the controller side, you need to add class to put all the field.

Here, MemberSearchExistingDto could have name and birthdate field.

In the html:

```
dataExist = JSON.stringify({memberSearchExisting:{name: memberFullName, birthdate: memberBirthdate}});
```